# Pandas: boxplot of one column based on another column

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like the following:

```
my_dataframe:

   Age  Group
0  31   A
1  24   A
2  25   A
3  36   A
4  50   NaN
5  27   A
6  49   A
7  24   A
8  63   A
9  25   A
10  65  A
11  67  A
12  59  A
13 NaN  B
14  30  B
15  19  B
16  57  B
17  62  B
18  30  B
19  50  B
20  42  B
21  45  C
22  59  C
23  28  C
24  37  C
25  29  C
```

I would like to boxplot the age of each Group (A,B,C). **Note** that I have some `NaN` values in the dataframe. How can I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Misread 1st time so gave answer for histograms... keeking that below.   for boxplot the code is:

```
bp = df.boxplot(by='Group')
```

[image]

```
suptitle('Bla Bla')
```

to change or get rid of the automatically generated top Title.

Might be a more elegant way but the following works for histograms:

```
df[df.Group =='A'].Age.hist()
df[df.Group =='B'].Age.hist()
df[df.Group =='C'].Age.hist()
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html has some fancy syntax to do this as well.   But since only have 3 groups the simple solution is probably sufficient.

Comment: Thanks.. Do you know how to get rid of `"Boxplot grouped X"` in the figure title?

Comment: Don't have the example data open anymore... if in ipython with pylab imports: simply title("Boxplot grouped X") should do.   Otherwise "import matplotlib.pylab as plt" and plt.title(".....")  should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Joop, unfortunately the title command just changes the part that says `Age` in the boxplot (in your post), that's why I asked.

Comment: "Boxplot grouped by Group" is in space used by suptitle.   but it merely over-writes stuff there so it stays messy.

Comment: My production pandas is still 0.10.0   Checked with 0.11.0 and suptitle is method to get to the other title.  Seems to be a bug using 0.10.0 that overwrites the subtitle, but the with invisibe background so previous one still shows.