# Pandas unravel count-column

Tags: python, pandas

Reading other questions [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984948/pandas-boxplot-of-one-column-based-on-another-column) I am under the impression that pandas does boxplots or doing statistical analysis best when the data is in the following format:

```
    stimulus    vote
0          1       0
1          1       1
2          1       1
3          1       1
4          1       2
5          1       2
6          1       2
7          1       2
8          1       2
9          1       2
10         1       3
11         1       3
12         1       3
13         1       3
```

where `stimulus` is my independent variable and `vote` is each score given to it.

However my data already comes grouped by `rating`, with another column `votes` showing the `.count()` of each vote.

```
    stimulus  rating  votes
0          1       0      1
1          1       1      3
2          1       2      6
3          1       3      4
```

again, `stimulus` is my IV, `rating` is the score scale and `votes` is the number of votes given to each score.

I am now having trouble working with that format and I can't even find out how I can transform this data back into the "stacked" or "record" format.

In the end I want to

- plot the data as a boxplot
- execute a Kruskal-Wallis H-test

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')

stacked = pd.DataFrame({key: np.repeat(df[key].values, df['votes'])
                        for key in ('rating', 'stimulus')})
```

yields

```
    rating  stimulus
0        0         1
1        1         1
2        1         1
3        1         1
4        2         1
5        2         1
6        2         1
7        2         1
8        2         1
9        2         1
10       3         1
11       3         1
12       3         1
13       3         1
```

What you posted as the `vote` column I am calling the `rating` column. If I understand your situation correctly, the values in the `stacked` `vote/rating`s column are ratings. So I think it is appropriate to call the column `rating`. (Moreover, it allows me to use a dict comprehension which is -- okay, I admit it -- the real reason for the name change. :)